# Change default signin & signout routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

So i want to change the sign in route to `/login` (instead of */users/sign_in*).

I searched around and found on the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) the steps. But i'm a little bit new to rails and just following the Steps didn't help me out.

My routes.rb is below:

```
resources :categories
root :to => "listings#index"

get "user/show"
resources :listings

get "flatuipro_demo/index"

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registration => "registration",
                                                                         :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
get 'users/:id' => 'user#show', as: :user



resources :messages, only: [:index, :create, :new] do
    member do
        get :inbox
        get :sent
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it at the bottom, and it didn't worked for me the first time because i didn't restart the Server.

```
devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}
```

should work fine for everyone who want to change the path names.